# Start a second cmd with commands prewritten in it

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

Can I use one batch file to execute a command that says to open a new cmd window and runs new commands in that window, **without** creating a new batch file and telling it to open that new batch?

Comment: Using `start` as opposed to `call` will run a command in a new window, but if you're trying to something complex or have multiple things in the new Window you'd likely need another batch. What is your purpose for not wanting a whole other batch file? If you don't mind it being temporary it would be possible to `echo` a bunch of commands into a randomly created batch file, `start` that batch, then delete it/have it delete itself when it finishes.

Comment: Im trying to make an all in one single file tool to optimize windows, its working out pretty well, but I keep coming across random problems like this one.

Comment: sounds like you could probably get by with `start cmd c/ whatever` - it will basically open `cmd.exe` and execute your line and then close itself; can just have multiple lines of that. can read more [here](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) for reference